# git branch -- merged

Tags: git, merge

I just accidentally typed `git branch -- merged` instead of `git branch --merged` and now when I type it correctly, I see a new merged-in branch called "merged".

I'm not sure if this is a feature of git branch, or what.

It looks like it creates a new branch from my last commit of the current branch, and it looks like it is now merged it into my current branch. I can imagine some use cases where it would be nice to just create a new branch on the fly from the one I'm working on without checking it out, but I'm not sure why you'd use this feature (if it is one) and if there are any problems associated with it. When I do a `git branch` I see the new branch called `merged` and there is no diff between that and my current branch.

I didn't see anything in the man pages regarding this, though I'll admit it is an interesting feature.

Can anyone shed any more light?
Using `git version 1.8.5.2 (Apple Git-48)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`git branch -- merged` is effectively the same as `git branch merged`. Even though the `--` is not documented in the man page, it is used consistently with typical Unix command line options. It ends the options (you prefix with `-` or `--`). This allows you to specify branch names like `-f` or `--merged`, which would otherwise be interpreted as options.

So, the command `git branch -- merged` simply creates a new branch called `merged`, pointing to the commit the current branch points to, without checking it out.

From the man page :

> git branch [--set-upstream | --track | --no-track] [-l] [-f]  []
>
> The command’s second form creates a new branch head named  which points to the current HEAD, or  if given.

Comment: The bare `--` ends options, so that you can supply things like path names that start with `-`.  For instance if you wanted to add file `-f` you could `git add -- -f`.  For `git branch` this is kind of pointless, but at least it's consistent. :-)